# Describe the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Am I correct in reasoning that all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that have order smaller than $n$ are zero divisors? Since all residue classes that are smaller than $\overline{n}$ are in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ we can find some $\overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for every element $\overline{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (with $|\overline{a}|<n$) so that $\overline{a} \overline{b}=\overline{0}$.

Also, is there some well known theorem stating this?

Comment: The first part of your reasoning is correct, but it is not true that all elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. For instance, $\overline{2}$ is not a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, since the only $b$ such that $\overline{2}\cdot \overline{b}=\overline{0}$ is $\overline{b}=\overline{0}$.

Comment: You can show that $\overline{m}$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $gcd(m,n)>1$.

Comment: By "order", do you mean additive order?

Comment: +1 for having chosen a username in agreement with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the statement is

$\mathbb Z_n$ with $n>1$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.

An element $\overline m\in \mathbb Z_n$ with $\overline m\ne \overline 0$ is a zero divisor if and only if $gcd(m,n)\ne 1$

To show that $p|m$ and $p|n$ implies that $\overline m$ is a zero divisor, choose $d:=\frac{n}{p}$ , then you have $\overline m\cdot \overline d=\overline {md}=\overline 0$

The (additive) order is an unusual way to verify whether an element is a zero-divisor.

But if a non-zero element $m$ has order smaller than $n$, then there is a number $d$ with $0<d<n$ and $\overline m\overline d=\overline md =\overline 0$ , so $m$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: This is slightly related with the question, but I don't think is the answer.